# How to use Ajax in BSP?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, sap-bsp

So far I've succeeded to get my BSP MVC model working.

Here is my code.

**View**

```
<body>
    <z:form>
   <z:input binding="//c/counter"
            invisible="true"/>
    Counter : <z:write binding="//c/counter"/>
        
    <z:button fcode="incr"
                      text="Increase"/>
    <z:button fcode="decr"
                      text="decrease"/>
    </z:form>
  </body>
```

**Controller** 

 Through fcode I invoke the "fcode_incr" method in Controller.
'c' is a model instance of zcl_counter.
it has an attribute counter which will be increased by this method.

```
method fcode_incr.
   c->increment( ).
endmethod.
```

I hope zcl_model is obvious and its code is not relevant here.

The problem when I press the "increase" button, server sends a request. When it gets the response, it refresh the page. So i get the incremented value.
how can I get it working with Ajax so the page remains without refreshing?

I've already tried Ajax with "XML page with flowlogic".
like "Eventhandler-->OnRequest"

```
request->get_form_field('variable').
```

Does it help any further?

***The correct* Ajax Call would be**

```
$.ajax({
        url:'ajaxController.do',
        statusCode:{
          404: function(){
            alert("not found");
          }
        },
        success: function(data){
          $('#viewData').html(data);
        }
       }).error(function(){
          alert("failed");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link explains the details: http://www.saptechnical.com/Tutorials/BSP/AJAX/create.htm

But, in essence;

1. Integrate some javascript in your bsp page so that you can do ajax, here are some options:

   - Either take the code from that link
   - Or the better the solution is to use jQuery, either through

     - Using  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />`
     - Or uploading http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js and referencing it in your code

   You can call ajax calls then like this with jQuery : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
2. Create a controller in your BSP project that will be called from AJAX.
3. Create a controller class for your controller, only re-define REQUEST and put your logic there

Done.

Comment: I have a controller named ZKTH_BSP_AJAX. How call it from Ajax?
xmlhttp.open("GET",controller ??, true); in this way?

Comment: The name of the controller is the name as it is exposed to the net, I am not sure I would call it ZKTH_BSP_AJAX. Regardless, you would call it with xmlhttp.open("GET", "ZKTH_BSP_AJAX" , true); Though really, I would invest time in learning AJAX calls with the jQuery library.

Comment: I've learned Ajax calls in JQuery. But I am not sure about how to implement it. I have an method in controller called fcode_save.
I should call this method, so i can catch the return value.
**`$.ajax({url: controller, data: inputName etc..})`**  where does the method come into?

Comment: Just to be sure, is your controller class derived from CL_BSP_CONTROLLER2 ? It must. Once you have that, you need to get the variables from the http request ( `l_year = request->get_form_field( 'year' ).` ) , call fcode_save and then return the output to the http request with `CALL METHOD response->append_cdata   EXPORTING data = l_output.`

Comment: Actually it inherited CL_BSP_CONTROLLER. so now I've created a new controller ZCL_CO_KTH_AJAX2 which derived from CL_BSP_CONTROLLER2. There i have methods like Do_init, do_request, do_handle_event etc.
In which method should i write `CALL METHOD response->append_cdata..`?

Comment: I have posted my code right at the bottom. I get an statusCode 404.
Does it mean that it couldn't identify the controller class?

Comment: Ah, okay. You might have missed step 2. Create a controller in your BSP project that will be called from AJAX. Right click on your BSP application, create a controller with a name, say 'doSomething' and link it to your class `ZCL_CO_KTH_AJAX2`. From then on, ajax should reference `doSomething`, not `ZCL_CO_KTH_AJAX2`. Also, the method `do_request` should have the `response->append_cdata` and the `request->get_form_field`.

Comment: that's great. it worked. thank you very much for your help. Now I can start to build. :)